# Get another row's data from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `categories` table:

```
| cat_id | cat_name | cat_desc | child_cat
```

What I want to accomplish is to get the cat name of `child_cat` if it exists.

sample data:

```
| cat_id | cat_name | cat_desc | child_cat
    1        test      testd       0
    2        test2     testd2      1
```

When I get the info of `cat_id = 2`, I also want to get the `cat_name` of `child_cat`.

Expected output:

```
| cat_id | cat_name | cat_desc | child_cat_name
    1        test2     testd2        test
```

Which method should I use?

Comment: Hint: Do a self join

Comment: If the child_cat_name is in the same table do as @MKhalidJunaid said or if you have two tables one for category other for child category then di INNER JOIN see at example https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comments, join the table with itself using a left join to not strip the categories that do not have a child.

```
SELECT t1.cat_id, t1.cat_name, t1.cat_desc, t2.cat_name as child_cat_name
FROM categories t1
LEFT JOIN categories t2 on t1.child_cat = t2.cat_id;
```

As Juan correctly points out, the aliases `t1` and `t2` need to be set since we are joining the same table twice and need to tell the SQL engine somehow to distinguish between the tables.

Comment: I want to add you need specify different alias so you can difference between the same table. In this case `t1` and `t2`